# Saving cross-domain Cookie in Safari

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, cross-domain

In safari there is a problem with the cookies of those sites that the user did not visit.

I mean, on google.com there is an iframe yandex.com. And the cookies that yandex.com put are not delivered because of the safari policy that I wrote above.

I found solutions to the problem:

Make a redirect to the site that is in the iframe, and then back to google.com - This method worked (But you understand this very clearly and does not look ...)

On google.com, create a form that will send a GET / POST request to yandex.com/cookies (allowable). In doing so, it will all work for ifarme (by setting the target attribute) - This method is not rolled.

Here's my question. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: I have somewhat similar query. does redirected works for you. as per Safari ITP 2.1 policy ,not sure if it does honor redirect as user visit to other site.